# How to localize UserControl

Tags: c#, windows

I'm developing a windows application that must support multiple language.

I've followed the article below http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.71).aspx to make my windows application localizable.

Everything works fine except the usercontrols. Do i have to create a usercontrol for each language? How to make the usercontrol inherit the Right to left property? What is the best practice to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UserControls have to be localized in the same way as forms (`Localizable = True`, `Language = ...`), you don't see the localization in the designer when they are embedded into a localized Form but during the runtime the localization is done well.

For the `RightToLeft` property: select your UserControl (select a control inside it and press ESC until the main control is selected - in the property panel you should see the name of your UserControl and the type = `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`), go to the property panel and search for the `RightToLeft` property, in the same panel you have also the `Localizable` and `Language` property that has to be used as you do in Forms.

Comment: ok, How can i change in the usercontrol designer? for example switching right to left and left to right?

Answer (score 0):

There are two components to making a User Control localizable, and editable in the Visual Studio Designer:

1. Set the top Form object's `Localizable` property to True
2. Define [control properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/attributes-in-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) that you want to localize and edit in the Designer like so (borrowed from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-apply-attributes-in-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)):

**C#**

```
[Category("Appearance")]
[Description("The title of the log data.")]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[Localizable(true)]
[HelpKeywordAttribute("AttributesDemoControlLibrary.AttributesDemoControl.TitleText")]
public string TitleText
{
    get
    {
       return this.label1.Text;
    }

    set
    {
          this.label1.Text = value;
     }
}
```

You may need to toggle the `Localizable` property and clean/rebuild your Solution before the data is reflected in the Resource file.