# Best way to localize UserControl in c# (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, user-controls

Do to my lack of knowledge I've edited this question

I am making a `UserControl` with `DataGridView` in it and I want to simplify implementation process as much as possible, so I am wondering should I do that with localization?
Do to my knowledge and [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp) thus far, my approach for localization is this:

For example say I have one button on my `form/UserControl` with text property set to "hello" , now I want to localize my `form/UserControl` for Italian language.

1. Set localizable property to true and choose language (in this case
   Italian)
2. Google translate
3. Set text property to "Ciao"

English is by default so i already have `.resx` file in my form, but after this VS will generate resources for Italian with `button.Text` property as **key** and "ciao" as **value**, if i understood correctly, but what happens if someone comes and change `button.Text` property from hello to "hello world", then my Italian resources won't be correct unless they are changed manually, is there a way to somehow do this change automatically?

I am wondering this, because when my `UserControl` with `DataGridView` is implemented on some `form`, I can't tell which columns will my `DataGridView` have, so I am wondering should I leave localization process to the person who implements my control?

Thank you, I really appreciate the help, and sorry for edit.

Comment: Don't user controls come with their own .resx file?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I can add .resx file in User Control but i would need a large amount  of strings in it, because I don't know on which form will be implemented

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood the question. I get it now.

Comment: If the columns of the `DataGridView`, are always the same, then a simple also good option is using [`Localizable` and `Language` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32990088/3110834) of the `UserControl` at design time. Best way is opinion based. It depends to different requirements. If columns are not the same and can be added by the user of the `UserControl`, then you don't need to provide localization in the control itself, the form should be Localizable and you need to just expose columns as a public property of your control.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thank you for ssuggestion, columns are not the same so you are right about form localization, but I am thinking long terms, if perhaps  new column is added or modified , how could I update `.resx` file automatically, i know that is not my job, but just started working and trying to prove myself, and perhaps I should edit the question

Comment: The time that you add the new column, add localized strings to the resource as well. To change a language or to add a new language you can distribute satellite assemblies.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thank you, nice suggestion but first time I've heard about  satellite assemblies I think this is a good [example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352105/Satellite-Assembly-Example-in-Csharp-Step-by-Step), If you have some extra time feel free to answer my question.

Comment: Seems your question is similar to [Best practice to make a multi language application in C#/WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119568/best-practice-to-make-a-multi-language-application-in-c-winforms). Good way is to move all localizable resources to separate satellite assemblies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to localize UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693979/how-to-localize-usercontrol)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option is to set the (localized) text using code (use **one** Resource file).
You can do this in your form's/user control's constructor for example.
Try to avoid using a resx per form/user control because this will probably lead to unmaintainable code (duplicated key/values) unless you use a third party tool to localize the entire app like ([Infralution Globalizer](http://www.infralution.com/products/globalizer.html) )

The above tool is not free,but it's the only one I've used

The code in your constructor will look like this (Assuming you have a YourResourceFile.resx)

```
public MyUserControl()
{
        columnFirstName.Header = YourResourceFile.FirstName;
        columnLastName.Header = YourResourceFile.LastName;
}
```

If you want to add more columns on your grid,you'll add:

1. a key in the Resource file
2. a new line in the constructor

In fact,step 1,usually, will not be necessary since the key will probably be there

**Update:**
There seems to be a popular VS plugin called [ResXManager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager) or ([here](https://www.visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b64e04c-e8de-4b97-8358-06c73a97cc68)).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I was thinking something like writing some code in `UserControl` constructor but you are right about unmaintainable code, thank you for the tool, though i won't use it now, I will definitely use some tool later on, now I am Interested in that code , and I will edit my question now.

Comment: @Yollo The code isn't anything complex,all you have to do is assign a property from a resource file.See my updated answer

Comment: but still I don't know what columns will `DataGridVIew` have, maybe I should use `loop`, checkout my updated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47874467/7517846)

Comment: @Yollo You will only localize whatever controls are on your usercontrol at "design" time.Whoever adds columns/gridviews on your control will be responsible for the localization of the new controls (again the best choice is by code)

Comment: thank you for answer, it was of help, if you find about some free localization tools, pleas let me know.

Comment: @Yollo I'll check but I don't really think it's worth it,too much trouble (I've done it). Better stick with one (or more if you want) Resource file just like you would do on a Web application

Comment: @Yollo I found a plugin (see the answer) but I guess you've already seen it.Didn't find any free tools but it looks like the commercial ones are relatively cheap,around 100 euro/dollars

Answer (score 1):

The Localizable Property of your UserControl should be set to true.

In addition any custom Properties of your UserControl you want translated should have the addition:

```
[Localizable(true)]
public string MyTranslatableLabel
{
    get;set;
}
```

You might also have to delete any instantiation like below from the Designer.cs file of the Form that contains the UserControl to get it to work properly:

```
this.myUserControl.MyTranslatableLabel = "Initial label of user control";
```

All this was tested on MS VisualStudio 2017 Community